# Como montar uma subconsulta com 7 tabelas?

Tags: sql

Estou querendo fazer uma subconsulta na minha query com 7 tabelas, mas eu só consigo fazer com duas tabelas.

- Código

```
SELECT COUNT(cd_cliente) AS qtd_cliente, 
(SELECT COUNT(cd_funcionario) FROM funcionario) AS qtd_funcionario FROM cliente;
```

- Resultado

```
qtd_cliente | qtd_funcionario
     2             2
```

- Restante do código

Como devo complementar esse subselect que deve retornar  também `qtd_fornecedor`, `qtd_compra_fornecedor`, `qtd_produto`, `qtd_venda`, `qtd_devolucao`

```
SELECT COUNT(cd_fornecedor) AS qtd_fornecedor FROM fornecedor, SELECT COUNT(cd_itens_compra_fornecedor) AS qtd_compra_fornecedor FROM itens_compra_fornecedor,
SELECT COUNT(cd_produto) AS qtd_produto FROM produto, SELECT COUNT(cd_venda) AS qtd_venda FROM VENDA, SELECT COUNT(cd_devolucao) AS qtd_devolucao FROM devolucao
```

- Resultado esperado

```
qtd_cliente | qtd_funcionario | qtd_fornecedor | qtd_compra_fornecedor | qtde_produto | qtd_venda | qtd_devolucao
     2             2                2                     3                   3            3            3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construa corretamente os subselects:

```
SELECT COUNT(cd_cliente) AS qtd_cliente, 
(SELECT COUNT(cd_funcionario) FROM funcionario) AS qtd_funcionario,
(SELECT COUNT(cd_fornecedor) FROM fornecedor) AS qtd_fornecedor, 
(SELECT COUNT(cd_itens_compra_fornecedor) FROM itens_compra_fornecedor) AS qtd_compra_fornecedor,
(SELECT COUNT(cd_produto) FROM produto) AS qtd_produto, 
(SELECT COUNT(cd_venda) FROM VENDA) AS qtd_venda, 
(SELECT COUNT(cd_devolucao) FROM devolucao) AS qtd_devolucao  FROM cliente;
```

Apenas acho estranho listar todas estas quantidades sem nada que as relacione, mas você deve ter suas razões e requisitos.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado amigo.